# Guava: merge two multimaps

Tags: java, guava

I have tree classes e.g. `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC`. `ClassA` and `ClassB` extends `ClassC`. I have two `Multimaps` - `Multimap<Integer, ClassA>` and `Multimap<Integer, ClassB>` and I would like to merge this two multimaps into one. I have tried find some solution but unsuccessfully. I have tried sth. like `Multimap<Integer, ? extends ClassC>` but I don't know if I make it right and if I can merge two multimaps together. Can someone help me? Thank you for response, I appreciate every help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Multimap<Integer, ClassC> combine(Multimap<Integer, ? extends ClassC> a, Multimap<Integer, ? extends ClassC> b) {
  Multimap<Integer, ClassC> combined = new SetMultimap<Integer, ClassC>();  // or whatever kind you'd like
  combined.putAll(a);
  combined.putAll(b);
  return combined;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`Multimap<Integer, ? extends ClassC>` would mean that the generic type can be any type that extends `ClassC`, but the type has to be fixed. i.e, it can be either all `ClassA` or all `ClassB`. So you should use `Multimap<Integer, ClassC>` instead. It will accept both the types `ClassA` and `ClassB`.